# How to forward a request to another URL with all request information (headers, ip etc.)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, httprequest, http-proxy

Please see below:

[image]

1. My app receives request from the user.
2. My app makes an API call to the 3rd party application using [request module](https://github.com/request/request).

**In order 3rd party API to work properly it needs to receive USERS IP and header information.** (It's an ad server). But when I send a request through my app -as expected- 3rd party receives my app server's IP and headers.

The question is:
How can I make my application's request to the 3rd party API to "seem like" the user? How can I "clone" the request of user's to 3rd party?

Thanks

Comment: Some products / parties support [X-Forwarded-For](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For). You'll have to resort to this or maybe a similar option because the IP the 3rd party receives will always be yours and you can't influence that (without issues). The other option is to get out of the middle and have the user call the 3rd party directly.

Comment: I **must** be in the middle :) X-Forwarded-For header option sounds cool. I'll check it, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For copying the headers, it sounds more like you need a [proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy).
For the IP: if im not completely off, i would say this is impossible as you have no influence on the IP Address that your Computer/Server gives to the packages send over the wire.

To put it in [OSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model)-Words: Your NodeJS Instance is on the Application Layer, while the IP Address is handled within the transport layer.

All I can think of you could do is to forward a link to your user to the actually 3rd Party API and let him call it.